# merging two SKShapeNode polygons into one

Tags: algorithm, swift, sprite-kit, polygon, intersection

I have multiple polygons (SKShapeNodes) on a sprite kit layer. All of them non-selfintersecting polygons. I would like to know:

1) if I introduce a new one, does it intersect any of the previous ones:

Does SKNode's: "func intersectsNode(_ node: SKNode) -> Bool" provide the means to do this? How can I iterate over the Node tree to check against all the existing SKShapeNodes?

2) the area of their intersection:

if the new polygon intersects and existing one, I would need to calculate the area of the intersection (e.g. the area in red in the picture below). Could someone propose a simple algirithm for this?

3) merge both of the polygons into a new SKShapeNode polygon and remove the two prior polygons from SKNode tree.

So after introducing a new polygon A that intersects a previously existing polygon B, I would like to remove both of the existing polygons A and B from sprite kit's node tree and introduce a new polygon C with a path that is the merge from paths of polygon A and B (in orange in the picture below)

I'm relatively new to Sprite Kit and graphics programming and not too comfertable with euclidean geometrics either. All suggestions on approaches how to proceed in these tasks greatly appreciated!!!

[image]

Comment: Hi, did you find out a way to solve this ?

Comment: I ended up creating my own polygon management with a library (http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~toby/gpc/) and erase all the sknodes and recreate them based on the polygons.

Comment: Really thank you, I'll try the library.

Comment: library is not swift is it?